# Google Maps: Attaching events on polyline icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a page where I'm trying to simulate ship locations on a map. Some of these ships are at a location a percentage of the way on a polyline, others are are at a single point marker.

With the ships that are a percentage of the way along a polyline, I'm able to display the icon correctly. What I'd like to do is attach events purely on that icon, and not on the whole polyline.

My code is at 
http://www.cleancruising.com.au/map_allShipLoc2.asp

I've also tried to alternatively calculate the LatLng of the ship location by using google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween, but as this uses spherical geometry, the points don't translate properly on a flat map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculating the LatLng of the ship location, see [this thread from the Google Maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/a6fe7d22d50de69f/caa9c1ebc470daff?lnk=gst&q=geodesic+polyline+projection#caa9c1ebc470daff), and the [example in it](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_geodesic.html)

Below is the modified GetPointAtDistance function modified from [Mike Williams' (v2) epoly library](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm)

```
// === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {return null;}
  var projection = this.getMap().getProjection(); 
  if (!projection) {
    alert("no projection");
    return; 
  }
  // Project 
  var p1= projection.fromLatLngToPoint(this.getPath().getAt(i-2));
  var p2= projection.fromLatLngToPoint(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  var m = (metres-olddist)/(dist-olddist);
  // alert("p1="+p1+" p2="+p2+" m="+m);
  // Unproject 
  return projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point( p1.x + (p2.x-p1.x)*m, p1.y + (p2.y-p1.y)*m));
}
```

Comment: Looking through this now. I think this will work nicely though. Thanks